# How to set reply to through vbscript before sending email

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook

I want to set reply to address before user is sending outlook email. I want to run vbscript and set reply to address. Please share the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MailItem.ReplyRecipients` collection.